# Get metadata string from Manifest

Tags: android, delphi

To get the string *versionName* inside the `<manifest>` key of the **AndroidManifest.xml** file, I use this code:

```
function GetFileVersionName: string;
var
  PackageManager: JPackageManager;
  PackageInfo   : JPackageInfo;
Begin
  PackageManager:= SharedActivity.getPackageManager;
  PackageInfo   := PackageManager.getPackageInfo(SharedActivityContext.getPackageName, TJPackageManager.JavaClass.GET_ACTIVITIES);
  Result        := JStringToString(PackageInfo.versionName);
End;
```

If the field﻿ is in a `<meta-data>` key, inside `<activity>` section, like this...

```xml
<meta-data android﻿:name="productName" android:value="HelloWorld" />
```

How can ﻿I ch﻿﻿﻿ange the above code to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution!
After move `<meta-data>` key outside `<activity>` section, code to read value for `name="productName"` is:

```
function GetProductName: string;
var
  PackManager: JPackageManager;
  AppInfo    : JApplicationInfo;
Begin
  PackManager:= SharedActivity.getPackageManager;
  AppInfo    := PackManager.getApplicationInfo(SharedActivityContext.getPackageName, TJPackageManager.JavaClass.GET_META_DATA);
Result:= JStringToString(AppInfo.metadata.getString(StringToJString('productName')));
End;
```